# How to reference a serializer in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers for both Product and Ingredient models, I want to use both relations in the frontend side. As products in Ingredient model (ingredient.products) and I want the same in Product model (product.ingredients), so how can I get it?

This is my code,

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # products = serializers.SerializerMethodField() //this line doesn't work

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

And the Ingredient modal,

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name="ingredients", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: # products = serializers.SerializerMethodField(). why is this not working? are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = '..', '..', 'ingredients'
```